# SQL Update using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-update

I want to update ManufID with ProductType of -1 and replace it with ManufID that has a ProductType of 1. I have this sample record:

```html
<table border="0" style="font-size:10; font-family: Lucida-Console; border-width: 4px; cell-spacing:0px; cell-padding:2px;">
 <thead><tr>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">AltID</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">ItemID</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">ManufID</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">MaxCount-Manufid</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">ProductType</th>
 </tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadcs</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadep</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadfj</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadmn</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadnk</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadfj</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadkd</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadnk</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadol</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">olacad</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Once updated, results should be like this:

```html
<table border="0" style="font-size:10; font-family: Lucida-Console; border-width: 4px; cell-spacing:0px; cell-padding:2px;">
 <thead><tr>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">AltID</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">ItemID</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">ManufID</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">MaxCount-Manufid</th>
  <th style="font-weight:bold;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-size:14;">ProductType</th>
 </tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadcs</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadep</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadfj</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadmn</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadnk</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadfj</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadkd</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadnk</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">dpacadol</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;font-size:12;">
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">acadun</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">olacad</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">1213</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">241</td>
   <td style="font-family: Tahoma;font-size;10;">-1</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm thinking of using the ROW_NUMBER when updating the records but i dont know yet how to use it :-)

Comment: Why do you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` if your goal is to update based on specific conditions? You may want to use a `WHERE ProductType="-1"` and for setting the value you may need to select `manufid` with ProductType="1" on your update statement.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's possible to use ROW_NUMBER() in that kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This will set the `ManufID` of all rows that have a `ProductType` of `-1` to the `ManufID` of the first row that has a `ProductType` of `1`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ManufID = (SELECT ManufID FROM yourTable
               WHERE ProductType = 1 LIMIT 1)
WHERE ProductType = -1
```

Note that this could be problematic if you have multiple rows with a `ProductType` of `1` and different `ManufID`s. In this case, you have to decide which one of the values you want to use.

Comment: Thank you TimoSta. Yes you're right, actually i have already came into that scenario wherein i will not include those records that has a ProductType of 1 with different ManufID s.